# SSL Enabled Storm Kafka Spout

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, apache-storm, bigdata

I wated to know is there any Kafka Spout which supports Secure Kafka Brokers.
KafkaSpout from apache storm is not having any support for SSL Kafka.

```
public KafkaSpout(SpoutConfig spoutConf) {
    _spoutConfig = spoutConf;
}
```

Below mentioned Kafka not taking in any parameters for SSL Kafka producer/consumer support.

```
public KafkaConfig(BrokerHosts hosts, String topic) {
        this(hosts, topic, kafka.api.OffsetRequest.DefaultClientId());
    }

    public KafkaConfig(BrokerHosts hosts, String topic, String clientId) {
        this.hosts = hosts;
        this.topic = topic;
        this.clientId = clientId;
    }
```

Please let me know is there any way we can achive the secure Kafka Message Stream Processing with storm topology.

Answer (score 1):

Storm's old kafka-spout uses simple consumer API for which security is not supported. If you are looking to use SSL with kafka consumer you should be using 
https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/external/storm-kafka-client
Here are the details
https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/docs/storm-kafka-client.md

To enable SSL its similar to what you would do regular kafka-consumer, you can follow the details in here 
http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#security_ssl

Comment: May I know from which version of storm it's available we are using storm 1.0.1 & Kafka 0.10.0.0 please let us know the dependency's we should use to avail this feature

Comment: Also please help with below mentioned quetion as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43141543/storm-kafka-failed-message-replay-throws-null-pointer-exception-in-spout

Comment: Its available in Storm 1.0.1 as beta quality. Recent release of Storm 1.1 consists stable version of storm-kafka-client. It can be used against Kafka from 0.10 onwards.